# set the projection of map in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I just want to convert the default projection of an Openlayers 3.9.0 from the default `EPSG:3857` to `EPSG:4326`.

So I edited a basic code like

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var center = [-1.812, 52.443];

var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:4326',
        units: 'm'
});

var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 6,
    projection:proj
});


var map = new ol.Map({
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: false,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting:false,
    target: 'map',
    layers: [layer],
    view: view

});
```

If center is like `var center = [-1.812, 52.443];` it does not go in the UK, as is should be, it goes in the center of the map.

If I do like `var center = new ol.geom.Point(-1.812, 52.443);` I see no map at all. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

You should not instantiate the EPSG:4326 projection by yourself, it's done by OpenLayers 3. You get the projection by calling `ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326')`.

The `ol.source.OSM` source loads it's tiles from services that only support `EPSG:3857`. Since it's a XYZ-based tilesource, you might actually get the map working (if the tilecoords are valid), but the layer will not be positioned correctly and still be in `EPSG:3857`. You can use `EPSG:4326` as the view projection, but then you have to use a background map that supports it.

A working demo can be found in the [official examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/epsg-4326.html).

Comment: Hi Alvin. So, in the example you link, the layer is by default `4326`, that's why the view is also `4326`. Did I got it? -Also, what if I want to have 2 different rasters with different projections? How can I do this, since I cannot reproject rasters? Thanks

Comment: No, because the view is configured with 4326, the wms layer is loaded in 4326. The same layer could probably be used with 3857 (provided that the wms server supports it). You can not currently mix raster projections in ol3. See Bob Holmes' answer for details on client side reprojection.

Answer (score 1):

OL does not currently transform tiles, but that is being worked.

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3785

Comment: Hi there. So, wait, I can not reproject the map because the only layer I am using is raster? What if I was using a raster and a vector? I would have to reproject the vector to much the raster? And what if I had 2 raster layers with different projections. Thank you man PS - I Use openlayers version 3.9.0

Comment: That's right.  You can transform vector layers to match underlying tiles but not vice versa.

Comment: Though it looks like that capability is getting close:  https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4122